# Self-Replicating Scammer Spammer - Randomizing Popup Positioning (Chrome)

Tags: javascript, html, random, popup, positioning

Self-Replicating Popup WORKS! However in CHROME the popups just stack on top of each other. WAS looking for assistance on how to make them appear at random positions. **Have edited question now that it's solved.**

To give you an idea, here is the code **I WAS** using to make the popup replicate itself (JS only, I don't need to show you how to implement full-page YT videos):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){ window.open("file:///C:/Windows/System32/popup.html", "", "width=300, height=200") }
    window.onunload = function(){ window.open("file:///C:/Windows/System32/popup.html", "", "width=300, height=200") }
</script>
```

The idea is that the popup is just a HTML file hidden in the VM (hence why no JQuery, AJAX, etc).

**Finally:** I would really appreciate the help. Whoever is the first to post the best solution gets best answer, and shoutout in credits of the released app and future YT videos (demos and DIY tutorials). Also be kind, web dev isn't my strong suit!! Thanks guys.

**NOTE ABOUT ANSWER:** Syntax has slight mistake at the end (I didn't even notice at first took me about 10 minutes of staring at it scratching my head to notice.

```
window.open('about://blank', '', 'width=300, height=200, top='+(Math.random()*screen.height)+', left='+(Math.random()*screen.width)+'')
```

It's exactly the same as the answer supplied by Villa7_ but you missed the [ + ' ' ] in between the two parentheses at the end, and for some reason dreamweaver (I know, leave me alone) kept flagging up a syntax error whenever I added the semicolons...

Thank you though, this was EXACTLY what I was asking for :) for some reason I can't give a vote though, only select your answer. Will give you the shoutouts I promised :) Very simple, love it!

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

random position:

```js
window.open('about://blank', '', 'width=300,height=200,top='+(Math.random()*screen.height)+',left='+(Math.random()*screen.width));
```